# What is the equivalent of a .pyw file in C++?

Tags: c++, python, silent

So I know that the python language has .py and .pyw extensions,the difference being .pyw run silent and there is no pop up, is there something like this in C++? If not, is there something I can put my code to run it silently? Of an alternative way to launch it?

Comment: It's a linker option (the subsystem). At least it is in Windows. I don't know how portable that is.

Comment: Just out of curiousity: Does this mean, that when on windows you give a file a different name, it behaves differently? Or are these "silent" files created differently and it is just a naming convention? (genuine question)

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Normally Python scripts on Windows are run by the `python.exe` interpreter, which *always* opens a Windows console if not currently running on one so that e.g. `print` works properly. Giving a Python script a .pyw extension runs it with the `pythonw.exe` interpreter, which does *not* open a console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one. On Windows, simply implement [`WinMain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as your entry point instead of `main()`, and change your linker options to create a GUI app instead of a console app. On *nix no change is required.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll look for a way to do that in Linux as well.

Comment: @ShockWave: There isn't anything *to* do. "On *nix no change is required."